# Solr highlighting of multiple terms

Tags: solr, highlighting

I have configured Solr so that the terms I'm searching are highlighted, but if those terms are far between them, I will only see the first one in the highlighting snippet.

What I want is to have something similar to Google's: separating snippets with an "ellipse" (...) so I can see the multiple terms in their context at once.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the `hl.snippets` parameter. It defaults to 1, and determines how many (maximum) snippets each highlighted field returns in each document.

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.snippets

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to cross post but I hope this question (which hasn't yet been answered) is very relevant to the above one..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326758/solr-highlighting-multiple-terms-what-is-the-separator

Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: The link posted above is dead.